# Como personalizar o botão anexar arquivo no aspx

Tags: css, asp.net, button

Estou com dificuldades para mudar o texto do botão de anexo de arquivos.
O meu botão está com o texto assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria alterar o texto do "Procurar..."
Teria como?
Estou fazendo em asp.net.

Segue código do upload:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Arquivo:</asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuArquivo" runat="server" Width="400px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isto não é tecnicamente possivel, por motivos de segurança. Se não, o usuário poderia ser "enganado".

Contudo, existe outros métodos para resolver isso, embora estes exijam trabalhar com HTML puro em vez do controle de servidor .NET -[veja aqui](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) para ter uma idéia.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94316/how-to-change-the-text-of-the-browse-button-in-the-fileupload-control-system-we)